# Embed a p5.js sketch on a Docusaurus docs markdown page

Tags: markdown, processing, p5.js, docusaurus

We are using Docusaurus as a documentation portal.  We would like to help illustrate some concepts with Processing (p5.js).

How can we embed a p5 sketch in a Docusaurus docs page?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Docusaurus, having a look it seems you can [mix markdown with react jsx](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react). I wonder if it's able to handle some basic html(e.g. if you add a basic p5.js sketch's html content alongside markdown with p5.min.js in the same folder: will it pick it up) ? If not, maybe getting p5.js into a react component first might work. Also looking at [Architecture](https://docusaurus.io/docs/advanced/architecture) (src/pages/index.js, plugin-content-pages in particular) and [plugins](https://docusaurus.io/docs/advanced/plugins) I wonder

Comment: ...if making a p5.js Docusaurus plugin would be a way forward. A bit hacky, but if basic html works, you cloud load iframes of sketches you've developed/tested outside of Docusaurus (though this might limit interaction between the iframe and the rest of the markdown)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Actually, I already use an iframe to embed YouTube videos, so that might be the easiest approach for Docusaurus, as well.